# No operating system or formatted partition(s) on laptop

Tags: installation, partitioning, format

I have about 20 IBM Lenovo ThinkPad laptops, R52, that are being donated to a school in the Dominican Repulic.  There is absolutely nothing on them!  I am trying to load Ubuntu Mint on them and have it installed on one of the laptops, from a CD that I burned with the software and during the setup, step 4 of 8, (prepare partitions) it got stuck.

There is nothing listed there so I went to the terminal and got the gparted software but when I `sudo lshw -C disk`, it only lists `*-cdrom`.  I used the `sfdisk` command and try using the menu options, nothing works.  Does that mean the hard drive isn't formatted at all and that is why Ubuntu can't see it?

I am not a programmer, just thought this was the best option for these laptops.  Any advice you can give me on formatting the partitions would be highly appreciated.

Please share step by step with me in the Linux language.

Answer (score 0):

considering lshw says there is only the cdrom, I would suggest you to:

1 Check the physical disk is inserted and powered on your laptop, what lshw is saying is there is no disks in this computer.

2 check your laptop bios, search for the boot options, verify your laptop find the hard drive.

3 If you are using a live cd, you could open a terminal and write:
  sudo lshw -html > myhardware.html
  Then you could read the specs from your pc with via a web browser:
  firefox myhardware.html
  This will tell you all about your laptop hardware.

4 If all else fail, you can burn a live cd of gparted, I think it has more options to detect your disks.